# sending sms using empathy

Tags: bluetooth, empathy, phone, sms

I've got gnome-phone-manager installed on ubuntu 12.04, and noticed it adds an SMS account type to Empathy. The only setting required to set up is 'bdaddr' which I think is a blue tooth address. i setup everything by blue tooth settings and configure in empathy. but no sign of using it feature